# Python Registration Error

Tags: python, add-on

I have been using Blender for a bit, I have made an animation, rendered images and many other things. I was using Blender 2.8 Beta and it worked great for a long time. However, it stopped working now, I can't use hotkeys or the mouse while in Blender but everywhere it works. I have done a clean reinstall, repair, removing user preferences. However, nothing works.

I have heard it is a possible Python Registration Issue. I am not sure what that means or how it happened. If anyone knows please help. Blender is literally unusable right now.
Below are images of some of the error codes I receive, as well as a screen shot of the keymap preferences because it is empty for some reason.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a portable build? And do you have Python installed on your Computer? What's your OS?

Comment: I have it installed on my Laptop, it is an Acer Aspire 3  with a Radeon Mobile Gfx  AMD Ryzen 3, a Vega 3 graphics Card and Windows 10(64 bit)

Comment: To me it looks like an add-on that isn't properly working and tries to register itself again, despite already being registered. Can you please open your installation directory of Blender (likely `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender`) and run the `blender_factory_startup.cmd` (double click on it). Does it make any difference?

Comment: Hello again rjg, I want to thank you again for trying to help me. I am testing it right now... Just tried it and thats a no. Doing that made less of the menu bars work so it got worse lol...

Answer (score 0):

If you go in edit / preference / keymap you should be able to reset the mapping left or right mouse selector it and put back the left click.

<sub>(translated with google)</sub>